# Fastest Way To Get Count From A Table With Conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, count

I am using sql server 2017 and EF Core 2.2. One of my tables right now has 5 million records in it.

I want to group all these records by "CategoryId" and then have a count for each one.

I also need to filter out with a where clause.

However even if I write the query in Sql it still takes around a minute to get me these numbers.

This is way too slow and I need something faster.

```
select CategoryId, count(*) from Items where Deleted = 'False'
group by CategoryId
```

I am guessing that EF core probably won't have a solution that will be fast enough so I am open to using ado.net if needed. I just need something that is fast.

Comment: You have 5 million records.  What do you expect?

Comment: Do you have any index on the table?

Comment: Have you checked the query plan?

Comment: Statistics and an index are going to be key here. With out a query plan, however, we have little to go on. But if you have 5million rows, but 2milliom different values for the ID, then I'd (personally) say that a minute is pretty quick

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) to materialize the aggregation:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ItemCategory
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT CategoryId, COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountBig
FROM dbo.Items
WHERE Deleted = 'False'
GROUP BY CategoryId;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_ItemCategory
    ON dbo.ItemCategory (CategoryId);
GO
```

Using this view for the aggregated result will improve performance significantly:

```
SELECT CategoryId, CountBig
FROM dbo.ItemCategory;
```

Depending on your SQL Server edition, you may need to specify the `NOEXPAND` hint for the view index to be used:

```
SELECT CategoryId, CountBig
FROM dbo.ItemCategory WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

Comment: @MJH, absolutely. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I already have an index for ItemCategory which is non unique, non clustered so not sure if I got to change that to what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You better add indexes on "deleted" and categoryid.
Or put all deleted items on a separate table

Comment: I have it on CategoryId already but not 'Deleted' I can try adding an index for that.

Comment: That does help by bringing it down to 13 seconds but still kinda of slow. I have a request to show on the page a breakdown of each category and how many items we have on each. How do people usually show these kind of statistics without making it the user have to wait around too long?

Comment: You should not request the whole table every time.you can use a customised pagination in the front end(bring 10 element in each page for example).or make it an asynchronous task.which means select the needed categories then use an ajax request to give the number of deleted items for a specific category.i hope it helps.sorry for my english

Comment: @chobo2 have a look at my answer and try with my suggested index.

Comment: @khalidMZIBRA - I only have 5 categories so there is no need to pagination  I just need to disable the name of the category and a count of non deleted items and to show this as fast as possible

Comment: If so you can create a table that contains the amounts of deleted items of each category. The table must be updated periodically

Comment: @khalidMZIBRA please stop, you started off with a good suggestion in your answer but since then in every comment your advice has gotten worse and wrose (pagination and now stored count)  :)

Comment: @ali can you explain me how my advices are getting worse

Comment: @khalidMZIBRA I would love to but dont have the time and energy to explain why your suggestions are "Bad Advice" but if you do have a DBA in your organisation, put forward your suggestions to him and see what he/she has to say about your suggestions :) and then ask that person to explain why he does not agree with your approach for a simple count :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.when you will have time you can explain why i am wrong.so the future viewers can benefit of you experience.regards

Answer (score 0):

You should have a covering index for your query to make it go fast, other than this there is no shortcut to get performance out of it as your query will need to read every page from the table to count the category ID.

I have a table with 5 million rows almost 4.7 million rows are set to Delete = False, without the covering index, my query takes about 12 seconds and execution plan looks like this.

[image]

Once I create the following covering index on my table the query is executed in less than a second and the execution plan looks exactly the same but it is doing a seek on the nonclustered index rather than doing a scan on the clustered index:

```
Index Definition:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test_Index]
ON [dbo].[Test] ([IsDeleted])
INCLUDE ([CategoryId])
```

[image]

With this covering Index SQL Server will only need to look into the index and return the results rather than looking into your whole table.

If you really want to speed up this query then there is another very specific way to speed up this query by creating a filtered index specifically for your query;

```
Index definition would be:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test_Index2]
ON [dbo].[Test] ([CategoryId])
WHERE IsDeleted = 'False'
```

With this filtered index my query was pretty instant, I didnt set IO time on my query but I would see a few milliseconds. The execution plan slightly changed with this index.

[image]

Comment: I have 2 non clustered index on this table now one for CategoryId and one for IsDeleted but I just did "create index ix_Items_Deleted   on Items(Deleted)" which is different then what you did. Is this just a different way of creating the same thing?

Comment: @chobo2 two separate indexes are not going to help a query, please google and read on the concept of "convering index", you need to provide one single index that covers/has all the columns your query need to query to bring back you results. Two separate index will not help as neither of them is a covering index for your query.

Comment: Ok, I will do more research on it but what happens if I need to through a join into the mix what I probably will have to do now thinking about it as I need the CategoryName to display.

Comment: @chobo2 because you already have CategoryID in your index it will help the join too, but I am guessing your other table is fairly small (from where you will be getting the Category Name) so it should be ok. But as they say, there is only one way to find out, give it a go :)